# Objective-C: Data Structures to save/restore complex data in/from a file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am in a situation that I would like to get an advice before go ahead and start coding. I have a document can have 1-1000 pages, some of the pages in the doc contain rectangle(s) which I have keep tacking of those (save CGRect) when document gets open and close, what i want to do is saving those rectangles associated for each page in some data structure that I can save them as metadata to a separate file associated to that document, so when I open the doc, i open that file and read the data(rectangles) for each page, then I can render them with each page(imaging them as highlighted rectangle in each page made by user. each page could have few of them. Now my question is what would be the best approach to organize the rects for each page in a data structure that can be saved/restore to a file? that means indexing to find the page, and from there, find the collection of rect(s) in that page, and save whole data for the specific doc to that file.
Any idea or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest reading through the [Archives and Serialization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1), specifically, how to use the [`NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSKeyedArchiver) and [`NSKeyedUnarchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSKeyedUnarchiver) classes which can handle serializing arbitrary data to files or network connections.

For any Objective-C class you want to save, have the class conform to the [`NSCoding` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCoding) and implement saving the `CGRect`s in the `encodeWithCoder` and restoring from save in `initWithCoder`.

Comment: I think there is one more way and it's using Core Data